# Подсчёт элементов сгруппированных данных с помощью Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

Здравствуйте.
Помогите, пожалуйста, со следующей задачей.
Есть поток данных типа `Person`. Вот описание класса:

```
public class Person {
    private String lastname;
    private String city;
    public String getLastname() {return lastname;}
    public String getCity() {return city;}
}
```

Нужно сгруппировать данные потока по городам (`city`) и подсчитать количество жителей (`Person`) каждого города.
Решить нужно при помощи `Stream API`.

Как я понимаю, в результате должно получиться что-то типа `Map<String, Long>`.
Пока получается только получить список типа `Person` для каждого города, т.е. `Map<String, List<Person>>`

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, List<Person>> map = persons.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getCity));
}
```

Как получить `Map<String, Long>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   Map<String, Long> map= persons.stream().collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getCity, Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать следующую конструкцию в методе collect:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
```

Comment: Не компилируется: `identity() in Function cannot be applied`